# How to call constructor if function has the same name

Tags: c++, constructor, overload-resolution

If I have the following:

```
class T
{
   public: 
      T(){}
};

void T()
{
}

int main()
{
  T(); // this calls the function, how can I call the constructor T()?
}
```

I have no any issue with it, since I could be possible to rename it, but just curious how I could force it to call the constructor, and also I am asking to myself why the function call seems to have higher priority than the constructor. Additionally, why is there no warning message in regards of the duplicate name.

Comment: simple, don't give them the same names.  Or dont use the parens with the constructor.

Comment: @MooingDuck: "don't " While it is a decent advice, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Besides what jaunchopanza said, you can qualify the call:

```
T::T();
```

With this version, you can create temporaries:

```
class T
{
   public: 
      T(){}
};

void foo(T) {}

void T()
{
}

int main(){
   foo(T::T());
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure my answer was correct. The function seems to mask the `T` default constructor, at least on my gcc 4.8 snapshot.

Comment: BTW does that compile for you, and if so, with what compiler?

Comment: @juanchopanza, it compiles in G++ and clang++ (4.4.3, and 1.1, resp). Oddly, so does `foo(T::T::T::T::T::T::T());`

Comment: @juanchopanza compiles for MSVS and on ideone.

Comment: This is not a well-formed program, according to C++2003, 3.4.3.1/1a. *Such a constructor name shall be used only in the `declarator-id` of a constructor definition
that appears outside of the class definition.* Note that the standard's example, which is supposed to fail, compiles successfully on g++.

Comment: @Robᵩ yeah, it looks wrong to me too. Add an answer, +1 from me.

Comment: @Robᵩ OK, I was going to say, it doesn't compile for me on gcc 4.6.3, 4.7 or 4.8 snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  there is not name collision, basically, there are in different namespaces

```
T() ==> namespace::T() It;s a function call not an object instantiation. 
T a() ==> namespace ::T::T() It;s is instantiation of T class calling the constructor.
T a() ; a() ==>namespace ::T::T()::() It;s call the functor of the T Class (need to define the operator())
```